# 3 divs, how to auto resize only 2, for a template

Tags: css

I have a template for a website that will be used for every page.  I want to have 2 divs auto re-size with the content.

http://jsfiddle.net/agroe070/9QGjH/2/

If the blue div has content larger than the div, I want the div to auto re-size to fit the content, and I want the green div to auto re-size as well so the bottom of the green div is still aligned with the bottom of the orange div. And vice-versa. The orange div will never be re-sized.

Answer (score 0):

These are the CSS declarations I changed, and it seems to work as required:

```
#wrapper{
    /* your other stuff */
    position: relative; /* to position the sidebar relative to this element */
}
#sidebar{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 190px;
    /* other stuff */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9QGjH/3/).

Comment: Thank you very much. However, it doesn't work both ways. http://jsfiddle.net/agroe070/9QGjH/11/

Answer (score 0):

use min-height instead of height and I think it will solve your problem